# Удалить столбец pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Не получается удалить столбец pandas ни с помощью del, ни с помощью drop, что я делаю не так?

```
        df = pd.read_excel(s_path, header=None)

        df = df.drop(0, 1)
 
        # del df[0]
        # df.drop(df.columns[[0]], axis=1, inplace=True)
    
        df.to_excel(s_path)
```

Пробовал перечисленные варианты (в т.ч. закомментированные)
По факту, только добавляется щапка с индексами

Comment: приведите пример данных чтоли

Comment: На самом деле проблема была в том, что я неправильно сохранял, без флага index=False.  Столбец пересоздавался

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame ({"a":[1,2,3,4], "b":[11,12,13,14]})
print(df)
```

```
   a   b
0  1  11
1  2  12
2  3  13
3  4  14
```

```
df.drop("b", axis=1, inplace=True)
print(df)
```

```
   a
0  1
1  2
2  3
3  4
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, на самом деле проблема была в том, что я неправильно сохранял, без флага index=False.  Столбец пересоздавался